# How can I get List of Images that directly linked with specific Page Items?

Tags: powershell-extensions

Have a scenario, where wanted to get list of Images which directly linked with marked page items.
Below is the powerShell script which I am trying, please help

```
$allImages = Get-ChildItem -Path 'master:/sitecore/media library/Images' -recurse -Language * -Version *

$results = @();

[string[]]$ItemIdList = Get-Content -Path 'D:\markedItemIds.txt'

$allImages | ForEach-Object {
  $properties = @{
  Name = $_.Name
  ID = $_.ID
  Path = $_.ItemPath

  LinkedItemIds = Get-ItemReferrer -ID $_.ID | Select-Object -Property ID

  //wanted to apply condition -> LinkedItemIds matched with ItemIdList if true then get value
}

$results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties

}

$results | Select-Object -Property ID, Name, Path, LinkedItemIds
```

Comment: Is there a reason your marked items are in a file rather than querying for matching items directly?

Comment: Hi @MichaelWest, yes there are individual Item Ids that randomly picked and listed to perform above operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `markedItemIds.txt` file contains comma separated IDs like `{ID1},{ID2}`, based on your powershell script I was able to filter the referrer ID's using:

```
$allImages = Get-ChildItem -Path 'master:/sitecore/media library/Images' -recurse -Language * -Version *

$results = @();

$ItemIdList = Get-Content -Path 'D:\markedItemIds.txt'

$allImages | ForEach-Object {
    $linkedItemIdResults = @();
    $LinkedItemIds = Get-ItemReferrer -ID $_.ID | Select-Object -Property ID

    foreach ($linkedItem in $LinkedItemIds) {
        foreach ($itemFileId in $ItemIdList.Split(",")) {
            if ($linkedItem.ID -eq $itemFileId) {
                $linkedItemIdResults += $linkedItem.ID
            }
        }
    }

    $properties = @{
       Name = $_.Name
       ID = $_.ID
       Path = $_.ItemPath
       LinkedItemIds = $linkedItemIdResults
    }

    $results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties    
}

$results | Select-Object -Property ID, Name, Path, LinkedItemIds
```